# Collision between a 2D Texture and a 3D model BoundingBox

Tags: xna, collision-detection, xna-4.0

I would like to check for collison between a sprite and a 3D Model.

After doing some searching I ended up with this code

```
BoundingBox handBox = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(handX, handY, 0), new Vector3(handX, handY, 0));
foreach (ModelMesh myModelMeshes in model.Meshes)
  if (myModelMeshes.BoundingSphere.Intersects(handBox))
    return true;
return false;
```

Here two values that should return false and not true

[image]

[image]

But the problem is that it's always true. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: To me it looks like they do intersect from the debugging information. The box is tiny and almost centered on the origin. The sphere is large (43 in radius) and it's only offsetted by a distance of 15 units which would make it intersect with the tiny box. Actually, the box is zero units wide, so it's infinitely small.

Comment: I will try to use a bigger rect and look in the radius thing then. Thanks for the tips

Comment: Your handBox(a dot) is inside your model, so this will always return true unless you move one model away from the other.